# Calling API in R (httr)

Tags: json, r, api, httr

I hope you can help me. I try to call an API in R (httr package).
API's address is :
https://apiv3.mojepanstwo.pl/dane/krs_podmioty

I try to get in R the same informations as listed under such adress:

https://apiv3.mojepanstwo.pl/dane/krs_podmioty?conditions[krs_podmioty.nip]=6321880539

How can I write it in R ? I tried as below :

```
URL <- "https://apiv3.mojepanstwo.pl/dane/krs_podmioty?"
ndsu_req <- GET(URL, query = list(condition[krs_podmioty.nip] = 6321880539))
ndsu_data <- content(ndsu_req)
nsdu_data
```

But I get some error. Specifically my intention is to get 3 numbers (nip) and list for them whole informations. Can anyone help ?

Comment: Try `list("condition[krs_podmioty.nip]" = 6321880539)`, otherwise the brackets are going to cause issues.

Comment: Yes, that helped me. Thank you. But how to build a list with 3 numbers to be searched ?

Answer (score 0):

I got answer for my problem. I wrote function + sapply for some nip numbers. But I got another issue: For one case I receive error:

"Index is out of bound."

I put that case in code below. This is because API returns no value for that object (DAtaObject[[1]]). Anyone know how to help and write a NULL value for that? Or any other solution ?

```
URL <- "https://api-v3.mojepanstwo.pl/dane/krs_podmioty?"



abc=c(
7822088970)

KAP<-function (abc){
DANE<- GET(URL, query=list("conditions[krs_podmioty.nip][]"= abc, limit = 1500 ))
DANE2<- content(DANE)
DANE3<- DANE2$Dataobject[[1]]$data$krs_podmioty.wartosc_kapital_zakladowy
DANE4<- DANE2$Dataobject[[1]]$data$krs_podmioty.nip
c(DANE3, DANE4)
}

sapply(abc,KAP)
```